# Need Algorithm to Allocating Managers to Stores

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman

Suppose you have "n" managers and "n" stores all located randomly across a geographic area. I need to be able to assign each manager to a store. The managers will travel daily from their homes to their assigned store. In general I'd like to minimize the daily distance travelled. This can be interpreted in two ways:

1. Minimize the average daily travel distance (which is also the same as minimizing the total travel distance.
2. Minimize the maximum travel distance for any single manager

Is this a known problem? Are there any obvious algorithms to solve it? It seems similar to the traveling salesman problem but it's not quite the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Both can be solved polynomially

I'll quickly cover both ways to define an optimal allocation as described in the question. Note that I won't make any assumption on the traveling times, such as triangle inequality. Of course such a property is likely to hold in practice, and there may be better algorithms that use these properties.

### Minimize total distance

For this instance, we consider the managers and the stores to be a weighted complete bipartite graph. We then want a matching that minimizes the sum of the weights.

This is called the [Balanced Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem#Balanced_assignment), which is a specific case of minimum/maximum matching. Because the graph is bipartite, this can be solved polynomially. Wikipedia lists a couple of algorithms for solving this problem, most notably the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

### Minimize maximum distance

If we wish to minimize the maximum distance, we can find a solution through a binary search. Specifically, we binary search over the maximum distance and attempt to find a matching that does not violate this maximum distance.

For any given maximum distance x, we create the bipartite graph that has edges between manager M and store S if and only if d(M, S) < x. We then try to create a complete matching on this bipartite graph with any bipartite matching algorithm, and through success and failure complete the binary search for the smallest x that allows for matching, thus minimizing the maximum distance.

Comment: What would be the complexity of binary search?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur That would be `O(log(x))` where `x` is the largest distance between manager and store, and the constant is dependent on the desired precision. Using for example Ford-Fulkerson to find the matching, that gives `O(n^2 log(x))` in total.